# Are the Jedi citizens of the galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Reading the now-noncanonical book *The Rise and Fall of Darth Vader*, I was surprised to find this passage:

> For the first time since he’d become a Jedi,[Anakin] found himself seriously considering the possibility of relinquishing his lightsaber, **leaving the [Jedi] order, and becoming a citizen of the galaxy**.

It appears to be suggesting that being a Jedi and being a citizen are mutually exclusive.

#### In canon, are the Jedi prevented from being citizens of the galaxy?

Comment: Note:   I typed this on my iPad, and when I wrote "The Rise and Fall of", the IPad predicted that the next word would be "Wickets".  *The Rise And Fall of Wickets.*

Comment: They probably meant "becoming a [normal] citizen of the galaxy."

Comment: @RedCaio - That's what I get for reading things too literally.

Comment: I'm guessing this may be analogous to "citizen of the world," an idiom that means someone who's not tied down to any specific nation, but travels (and feels an affinity for) many places.

Comment: In context, my feeling is that he just means a non-Jedi, in the same way that a policeman might distinguish between themselves and a "civilian"

Answer (score 8):

The word "citizen" [had a more specific meaning in the Middle Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship#Middle_Ages) than it does today, and did not encompass knights, who were considered somewhat higher on the social scale.  See also [this book excerpt](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=GWZZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT164&lpg=PT164&dq=knight%20citizen&source=bl&ots=_zsh0QsZMa&sig=OmwzrJCGDfxsJ3qwcW0MwGw81p8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig3ODhnLrKAhWGHpQKHQmhBDM4ChDoAQgfMAE#v=onepage&q=knight%20citizen&f=false).

Obviously, the Republic was not closely modeled on the Middle Ages, but the Jedi Order does appear to be more closely modeled on the [Knights of the Late Middle Ages than on the more modern variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight).  Although I'm not aware of any canon evidence either way, it doesn't seem too unlikely that Jedi were indeed considered distinct from citizens.